Get top 2 Upcoming Recurring Events- SP Classic exp Events
I want to display 2 upcoming events from my SharePoint Out of Box Events list.
I am unable to fetch the upcoming recurring events. I am using SharePoint Rest API to fetch the items from the list. I am able to fetch the recurrent data and parse the xml to get the weeks,frequency etc and calculate the next recurrence. But I need each recurrent event separately since this is too complicated and only provides me a single data.
Is there any way to do this using atleast by power automate?

It is also very complicated to get top 2 upcoming recurring events by power automate.
As a workaround, you could consider to use Outlook group calendar and group calendar web part to show upcoming recurring events.
